# How To Not Display The Output Stream When Message Is Sent Again On Same Socket?

Tags: java, tcp, server, tcpclient, tcpserver

```
in.read(Data,0,in.available());
System.out.println(new String(Data, "ASCII"));
Response="Your Request Is Being Processed"+S.getLocalSocketAddress()+"\nGoodbye!";
Data=Response.getBytes();
out.write(Data,0,Data.length);
out.flush();
```

In [DataInputStream] Out[DataOutputStream] Response[String] Data[Bytes[2048]]

Output:

Waiting 4 Client On Port : 11171...

Just connected to /192.168.1.5:6953

Waiting 4 Client On Port : 11171...

Now Waiting For Input....

Hello World 1234 !

Now Waiting For Input....

Hi This Is A Testeing Processed /192.168.1.5:11171

[This Merged Output I Donot Want Ethier It Should Be Displayed Or Not At All]

Goodbye!

Now Waiting For Input....

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: Copy and paste the output (or whatever) into the question.  Don't use links to transient drop-box type sites like imgur.com

Comment: Will This Much Info suffice ?